# After forced push - history is synchronized in other developer repositories - is it OK?

Tags: git

This is a follow up to my previous question here:

[Fix history after forced push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025757/fix-history-after-forced-push)

The question was why after forced push, history is not synchronized in other developers repositories. The answer was that other developers, after executing `git pull` will have their local history merged with the one from server. So if I removed a commit from the top and force pushed it, then it will still be there at the top in other developers repositories.

Now to the point, today I have been testing this scenerio once again (this time with company git server - it uses gerrit). And I see that above history merge does not happen.

What I have done:

I have a central repository, I have cloned it to two local folders. I have created a remote branch for testing, then pushed to it few commits. The log for them looked as follows:

```
git log --preety=oneline
962937062641327e4ad9d83ee7ead97f6c5a3bc7 One test change
08667125120a39b24c2006d5a63f6e1be61828a4 Code fixes - extra comment
...
```

Then made sure both of the local repositories are synchronized.

Then in local reposotory, lests say repo1, I have removed top commit with:

```
git reset --hard 086671251
```

and pushed repo1 with `git push -f origin HEAD:dev/mike-test3`

Then in the second local repozitory, I have executed `git pull`, and now what puzzles me is that commit 962937062 was actually removed, below is what git gave me on output:

```
git pull
remote: Counting objects: 10, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (6/6)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
From [...........]
 + 9629370...0866712 dev/mike-test3 -> origin/dev/mike-test3  (forced update)
   18ab880..bc08478  master     -> origin/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

Even `git status` shows me no pending commits to be pushed.

I have changed a commend slightly from the one in my previous question. From `git reset HEAD^ --hard` to `git reset --hard SHA1`, the previous one just didnt work for me (shouldnt HEAD^ be HEAD~1?).