Git commit no longer in the log after `git pull`
Yesterday I cloned a Git repository (hosted on a GitLab instance). The HEAD was some commit (26337128). Today, I did a git pull, but this commit no longer appears in the log (git log | grep 26337128 and git branch -a --contains 26337128 both give nothing). Why?
Note that the commit is still visible with git show 26337128 (and on the GitLab web interface), I did not do any local change, and I am still in the default branch.
EDIT:
Here's git reflog --all output, but I don't know how to interpret it:
8d0f83b389ec (HEAD -> drm-tip, origin/drm-tip, origin/HEAD) refs/heads/drm-tip@{0}: pull (finish): refs/heads/drm-tip onto 8d0f83b389ec64b9f7f9b2ee241fc352346868f1
8d0f83b389ec (HEAD -> drm-tip, origin/drm-tip, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: pull (finish): returning to refs/heads/drm-tip
8d0f83b389ec (HEAD -> drm-tip, origin/drm-tip, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: pull (start): checkout 8d0f83b389ec64b9f7f9b2ee241fc352346868f1
8d0f83b389ec (HEAD -> drm-tip, origin/drm-tip, origin/HEAD) refs/remotes/origin/drm-tip@{0}: pull: forced-update
26337128da9b refs/heads/drm-tip@{1}: clone: from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/tip
26337128da9b refs/remotes/origin/HEAD@{0}: clone: from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/tip
26337128da9b HEAD@{2}: clone: from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/tip


The commit you're asking about is present in your local repo; it is listed in the bottom three lines of the reflog.
As for what happened: Well, it would be more helpful if you said git reflog --date iso so we could see how much time elapsed between your actions; but, based on the reflog and the little hints you've dropped for us, evidently between your clone yesterday and your pull today, someone did a force push (notice the "pull: forced-update") — and so 26337128 was ripped out of the rewritten branch.
Of course, people are not supposed to do that kind of thing (force push to a shared branch). But evidently your gitlab remote isn't configured to prevent it.
Anyway, you do still have that commit if you want it (for now). Since it isn't on any branch any more, it will eventually be garbage collected if you don't pin it. For now, the reflog itself is retaining the commit.

OK, a forced push explains the issue, but I thought that this was strongly discouraged (i.e. never used except for exceptional reasons such as legal issues). Moreover, the git pull command did not even warn about the forced push. So poor design. And the fact that a remote commit can be garbage-collected is also bad (e.g. if one wants to reproduce an issue with the corresponding state of the source code).

"forced push explains the issue, but I thought that this was strongly discouraged" Yes, that's what I said in my answer. One is supposed to alert all other users (manually) when doing a force push to a shared branch. Someone has behaved badly.

I can't go into more detail without seeing the output of git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate. My answer, as I said was based on the very little information you provided. You might want to consult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063345/what-and-where-does-one-potentially-lose-stuff-when-git-says-forced-update, of which your question is arguably a duplicate.

Well, the git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate output has 1581190 lines, so this is probably too large to provide it. But 26337128 cannot be found in the output.

When doing a search, I did not see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063345/what-and-where-does-one-potentially-lose-stuff-when-git-says-forced-update whose title doesn't even mention git pull (thus it was not found in the search). BTW, this question mentions "forced update", which I did not see. But looking at an answer, the "forced update" text just appears in the middle of verbose output so is barely noticeable.

Sorry, I meant the "forced update" that is supposed to appear with git pull (as mentioned in the other question). I did not see this text. For something that people are not supposed to do, I would have expected some emphasized text, and even a failure without an option to accept forced updates (How to reject a forced update by GIT on client side when doing a git fetch or git pull? might have been a solution but this is not global and not the default either).

Hard to say. Perhaps your commit was already upstream (bright minds fix the same bugs). You'd have to dig deeper (look at the branches, e.g. with gitk).

If you still need that commit or want to understand how the history was changed, you might want to inspect the reflog with git reflog to see what changes occurred in the repository.

As I was really surprised, I just want to know what happened. I've added the full reflog output.

1.Displays the Reference Log 2.Shows History of HEAD Movements 3.Helps in Recovery

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
